# HTML setting an image for facebook

Tags: html, facebook, meta

**Disclaimer:**
I've google it and read some Q&A here so please avoid these suggestions.

**The Problem:**
I'm trying to set an image to display when the url of my site is being mentioned on FB like this:

```
<head>
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/image/theImage.jpg"/>
    <link rel="image_src" href="http://example.com/image/theImage.jpg"/>
</head>
```

and it doesn't work!

The image facebook selected is located on the body section like this:

```
<img src="images/Jil.jpg" alt="Jil" class="img-responsive">
```

What makes this even stranger is that the selected image is is not the first  `<img>` tag in the body section, so I don't understand the logic of how facebook selects the image to display

Comment: What you have should be fine.  Test here to ensure it's not a caching issue from a previous test:  https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/  Also, validate your HTML.

Comment: @Brad thanks for the link it shows that the image was too big.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When debugging Facebook tagging issues like this, it's worth using the debug page:  https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

In this case, it sounds like it told you that your image size was too large.

Additionally, it's always good to validate your HTML, as what might work for a browser might not work for whatever Facebook is using to parse that HTML server-side.  (The HTML in the question is fine, I'm just providing this advice for future folks that find this answer.)